# UIApplicationShortcutItem not showing base on Info.plist

Tags: ios, swift, uiapplication, swift4.2, uiapplicationshortcutitem

I have 5 items defined in my plist. It only showed 4. ‍♂️

I've tried in `Simulator` and the **actual** `iPhone XS Max`.

```
    <array>
        <dict>
            <key>UIApplicationShortcutItemIconFile</key>
            <string>home</string>
            <key>UIApplicationShortcutItemTitle</key>
            <string>Home</string>
            <key>UIApplicationShortcutItemType</key>
            <string>homePressed</string>
        </dict>
        <dict>
            <key>UIApplicationShortcutItemIconFile</key>
            <string>security</string>
            <key>UIApplicationShortcutItemTitle</key>
            <string>Security</string>
            <key>UIApplicationShortcutItemType</key>
            <string>securityPressed</string>
        </dict>
        <dict>
            <key>UIApplicationShortcutItemIconFile</key>
            <string>alert</string>
            <key>UIApplicationShortcutItemTitle</key>
            <string>Alert</string>
            <key>UIApplicationShortcutItemType</key>
            <string>alertPressed</string>
        </dict>
        <dict>
            <key>UIApplicationShortcutItemIconFile</key>
            <string>network</string>
            <key>UIApplicationShortcutItemTitle</key>
            <string>Network</string>
            <key>UIApplicationShortcutItemType</key>
            <string>networkPressed</string>
        </dict>
        <dict>
            <key>UIApplicationShortcutItemIconFile</key>
            <string>settings</string>
            <key>UIApplicationShortcutItemTitle</key>
            <string>Settings</string>
            <key>UIApplicationShortcutItemType</key>
            <string>settingsPressed</string>
        </dict>
    </array>
```

## Result

[image]

**Am I doing anything wrong ?**

Comment: with 2 fingers, does not seem to work on both simulator and iPhone.

Comment: is there by any chance you using iOS 9 ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [Apple](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiapplicationshortcutitem):

> The system limits the number of quick actions displayed when a user presses a Home screen app icon. Within the limited set of displayed quick action titles, your static quick actions are shown first, starting at the topmost position in the list. If your static items do not consume the permissible number for display and you have also defined dynamic quick actions using this class, then one or more of your dynamic quick actions is  displayed.

That is, the system dictates the maximum number of items displayed and picks the first n items you provide for display.

I can't find anywhere the exact limit is shown, but I havn't seen any app have more than 4 items + the "share" item.

Comment: I will try to add the 5th one as share, will see what I see.

Answer (score 1):

I think there is a limit of four items, looking into the [documents](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiapplicationshortcutitem)

> The system limits the number of quick actions displayed when a user
>   presses a Home screen app icon. Within the limited set of displayed
>   quick action titles, your static quick actions are shown first,
>   starting at the topmost position in the list. If your static items do
>   not consume the permissible number for display and you have also
>   defined dynamic quick actions using this class, then one or more of
>   your dynamic quick actions is displayed.

UPDATE discussion 
about the **Share** item:

> Apparently iOS adds SHARE automatically BUT only if the app is
>   installed from Appstore. – kyo

which make them four + the share item, as AppStore automatically have share application item added on each downloaded application

Comment: I will try to add the 5th one as share, will see what I see.

Comment: Some app show 5 with the share button.

Comment: The share usually shows up as fifth

Comment: even if we're not include them in the Info.plist ?

Comment: usually its there if you haven't exclusively define it. but if you have a primary list of items they override the share item

Comment: apparently iOS adds `SHARE` automatically BUT only if the app is installed from Appstore.

Comment: yea thats the right context of it, as it appears to be on every app i have on store where i didnt add any shortcut item.